# Elasticsearch Resource Leak

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using the transport client on v 1.3.2 as so

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elastictest").build();
Client client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("1.1.1.1", 9300));
```

I close the method with:

```
client.close();
```

Everything seems okay, except I get a nasty yellow warning under the words "new TransportClient(settings)" in Eclipse saying:

```
Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is never closed
```

It looks like this:

[image]

So my question is even though I am closing the client at the end of the method is there still a leak happening with the 'new TransportClient'? Or should I just ignore that warning in eclipse?

Per @Lucas reply this is now what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try using `try-with-resources`:

```
try(Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elastictest").build();
Client client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("1.1.1.1", 9300));) {
//your code
} catch (//your exceptions if any) {
//handle exceptions
}
```

It will automatically close resources when you're done with them and should quiet Eclipse down

Comment: Thanks @Lucas but when I do I get error under 'Settings' The resource type Settings does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable and another under TransportClient: The constructor TransportClient(Settings) is undefined.. well I guess then second is dependent on first

Comment: if Settings doesn't implement AutoClosable try declaring and initializing it before `try`

Comment: can you confirm on above image that even though there is still the yellow warning it will close itself at the catch w/no memory leak and without disrupting method?

Comment: Hey Lucas, I'm having the same trouble. But unlike ur solution I can't put all my code inside try-catch. Scenario is- Client will be initialized once inside a spring bean, and be used by methods throughout its lifecycle. Any idea ?

Comment: You can try closing it manually if you absolutely cannot use `try-catch`, you might get a warning but you'll know it'll work. However I'm really not sure...

Answer (score 2):

I found that separating the creation of the TransportClient and addTransportAddress stopped the warning:

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elastictest").build();
TransportClient client = new TransportClient(settings);
client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("1.1.1.1", 9300));
```

Good luck!